# easiest way to compare not trivial enumerable

Tags: c#

What's the easiest way to compare non trivial sequences without writing loads of custom code with boilerplate?

This example obviously doesn't work, but short of writing a completely custom routine, is there some sort of shortcut?

```cs
[TestMethod]
public void FooTest()
{
    var x = new[]
    {
        ("0", new[] { 0, 105}),
        ("1", new[] { 1 }),
        ("2", new[] { 2 })
    };
    var y = new[]
    {
        ("0", new[] { 0, 105}),
        ("1", new[] { 1 }),
        ("2", new[] { 2 })
    };

    Assert.AreEqual(x,y);
}
```

There is `Enumerable.SequenceEqual`, I assume I need a custom `EqualityComparer<>`? Which feels like a massive overkill when all I want to do is pass something to say whether a non null element a, doesn't equal a non null element b.

This is using MSUnit, but to be fair the question is general and ideally I shouldnt be assuming I'm using some testing framework, this is my best solution so far.

```
[TestMethod]
public void FooTest()
{
    var xs = new[]
    {
        ("0", new[] { 0,105}),
        ("1", new[] { 1 }),
        ("2", new[] { 2 })
    };
    var ys = new[]
    {
        ("0", new[] { 0,105}),
        ("1", new[] { 1 }),
        ("2", new[] { 2 })
    };

    static bool CompareEnumerable<T>(IEnumerable<T> xs, IEnumerable<T> ys, Func<(T, T), bool> isEqual)
    {
        if (xs == ys)
            return true;
        if (xs.LongCount() != ys.LongCount())
            return false;
        return xs.Zip(ys).All(isEqual); 
    }

    var areEqual = CompareEnumerable(xs, ys, xy =>
    {
        if (xy.Item1.Item1 != xy.Item2.Item1)
            return false;

        return CompareEnumerable(xy.Item1.Item2, xy.Item2.Item2,xy => xy.Item1 == xy.Item2);
    });

    Assert.IsTrue(areEqual);
}
```

but its quite inefficient (I'm checking lengths), and surely its a lot of code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which testing tool are you using? With `Xunit`, `Assert.Equal` method returns the expected result.

```
var x = new[]
{
    ("0", new[] { 0,105 }),
    ("1", new[] { 1 }),
    ("2", new[] { 2 })
};

var y = new[]
{
    ("0", new[] { 0,105 }),
    ("1", new[] { 1 }),
    ("2", new[] { 2 })
};

Assert.Equal(x, y); // true
```

Comment: Ideally I wanted it to not be in the testing framework....but maybe I'll just flip these tests into xunit and make my life easy

Comment: this is the answer I'm going to use in this context, though i may prefer the fluent answer in other contexts

Answer (score 0):

I think you want FluentAssertions' [`x.Should().BeEquivalentTo(y)`](https://fluentassertions.com/objectgraphs/)
 which compares the object graph.

I've also seen people serializing the objects to JSON and then compare the JSON instead.

Comment: I'll look up fluent assertions what framework is that? (though tbh I'd rather it wasnt dependent on a testing framework)

Comment: @MrDatKookerellaLtd: I linked to it. It's available as a NuGet package

Comment: I'm going to use the xunit version, just because it easy...but I think this answer is very good too